# How to order user by last activity date on Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have two tables `users` and `activities`

**Users table**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Ari |

**Activities table**

| user_id | desc | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Log in | 27/10/2022 13:00 |
| 1 | Log out | 27/10/2022 14:00 |
| 2 | Log in | 27/10/2022 12:00 |
| 2 | Log out | 27/10/2022 13:00 |

want to get like below result

| id | name | last_activity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 27/10/2022 14:00 |
| 2 | Ari | 27/10/2022 13:00 |

mainly `ORDER BY` last activity from another table, thanks for answers

Answer (score 0):

loadDirectorList is a functional reference. It returns some thing like (){}. In order to get array you need to call it loadDirectorList().

Due to low explanation of your code, I think this must be causing problem.

Comment: How to set array to options of `SelectAsync` element ?